# Como adicionar uma fonte personalizada no TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Eu estou usando `TCPDF`  para gerar uns PDFs (óbvio) e preciso adicionar uma fonte personalizada.

Dei uma olhada na [documentação](https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/) e lá fala que tem um método chamado `addTTFfont` .

O problema é, quando tento chamar, um erro é retornado, dizendo que o método não existe:

> Call to undefined method TCPDF::addTTFfont()

Esse método `addTTFfont` está em outro lugar?

Como adicionar fontes personalizadas no `TCPDF`?

Comment: Quem negativou pode explicar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira nota do link da documentação que você postou:

> NOTE: The following information is valid only fot the old TCPDF library. The new tc-lib-pdf library uses the new [tc-lib-pdf-font](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf-font) library that is able to convert fonts on the fly.

O atual método da biblioteca é `TCPDF::AddFont()`

```
/**
 * Imports a TrueType, Type1, core, or CID0 font and makes it available.
 * It is necessary to generate a font definition file first (read /fonts/utils/README.TXT).
 * The definition file (and the font file itself when embedding) must be present either in the current directory or in the one indicated by K_PATH_FONTS if the constant is defined. If it could not be found, the error "Could not include font definition file" is generated.
 * @param $family (string) Font family. The name can be chosen arbitrarily. If it is a standard family name, it will override the corresponding font.
 * @param $style (string) Font style. Possible values are (case insensitive):<ul><li>empty string: regular (default)</li><li>B: bold</li><li>I: italic</li><li>BI or IB: bold italic</li></ul>
 * @param $fontfile (string) The font definition file. By default, the name is built from the family and style, in lower case with no spaces.
 * @return array containing the font data, or false in case of error.
 * @param $subset (mixed) if true embedd only a subset of the font (stores only the information related to the used characters); if false embedd full font; if 'default' uses the default value set using setFontSubsetting(). This option is valid only for TrueTypeUnicode fonts. If you want to enable users to change the document, set this parameter to false. If you subset the font, the person who receives your PDF would need to have your same font in order to make changes to your PDF. The file size of the PDF would also be smaller because you are embedding only part of a font.
 * @public
 * @since 1.5
 * @see SetFont(), setFontSubsetting()
 */
public function AddFont($family, $style='', $fontfile='', $subset='default');
```

Depois, pode-se utilizar normalmente o método `TCPDF::SetFont();`

---

**Adendo**:

Apesar de eu considerar a TCPDF a mais completa biblioteca, ela é bem confusa em alguns aspectos e, em parte, por sua documentação...

Comment: Pois é. O método que eu vi aqui era `\TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont`, numa resposta do SOEN, kkkkk